# PHP erro de arredondamento de valor

Tags: php, float, int

Estou com um problema, depois de atribuir a uma variavel um valor float conforme abaixo, 
4.85, após multiplicar por 100, 48500 e quando vou imprimir com sai o valor de 00000000484.

```
$variavel = 4.85;
$valor = $variavel * 100;
echo sprintf("%011d",$valor);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se fizeres um `var_dump($valor);` o resultado vai ser :

> float(485)

Isso acontece porque estás a utilizar na função `sprintf` o <strike>d</strike> e deverias utilizar **f**, porque a variável `$valor` é um *float*.

d - O argumento é tratado como um **inteiro**, e mostrado como um **número decimal** com sinal.

f - O argumento é tratado como um ***float***, e mostrado como um número de ponto flutuante (do locale).

F - o argumento é tratado como um ***float***, e mostrado como um número de ponto flutuante (não usado o locale). Disponível desde o PHP 4.3.10 e PHP 5.0.3.

---

Podes também utilizar a função `number_format` para passar a variável `$valor` para inteiro, uma vez que esta se encontra como *float* e manter o teu código:

```
$variavel = 4.85;
$valor = $variavel * 100;
$valor = number_format( $valor);
echo sprintf("%011d",$valor);
```

Fontes: [Manual sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php); [resposta SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12183195/1817673)

Comment: Mas olhe a seguinte situação, estou transformando um float em um int, já que multiplico 4.85 por 100 e assim fica 48500, se ele pegar apenas a parte inteira pegaria o valor de 48500.00 ? Realmente desta forma consegui resolver o problema mas esta dúvida ficou na cabeça...,

Comment: Se fizeres um `var_dump($valor);` o resultado vai ser `float(485)`. 
Então tens de transformar primeiro num inteiro.

Comment: Pode utilizar também o `$valor = number_format( $valor);` e manter o teu código. para formatar para inteiro.

Comment: @MarcoAndré Resposta atualizada.

Comment: Obrigado @Jorge B. já alterei meu código estou utilizando sprintf("%011.0f",$valor);, é para um leiaute de arquivo para integração, obrigado pela ajuda e atenção !!

Answer (score 2):

Existe funções mais específicas para você trabalhar com números arredondados em php.

**Arredondar valores para cima:**

```
<?php 
    echo ceil(9.3);
    // saída = 10
?>
```

**Arredondar valores para baixo:**

```
<?php 
    echo floor(9.6);
    // saída = 9
?>
```

**Arredondamento automático:**

```
<?php 
    echo round(9.3);
    // saída = 9
    echo round(9.6);
    // saída = 10
?>
```

Use a forma que mais se adapta ao seu projeto.